# Google appengine - splitting traffic based on user

Tags: google-app-engine

With google appengine, is it possible to direct all new users to a specific version, while all the old users continued to be served by existing old version?
 Idea is not to confuse existing users with new enhancements but  will be seen only by new users.

Answer (score 2):

Note: didn't use it yet, answer is based solely on documentation.

It is possible, with some work for managing per-user cookies, via [Cookie splitting](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/splitting-traffic#cookie_splitting):

> If you choose to split traffic to your application by cookies, the
>   application looks in the [HTTP request header](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled) for a cookie named
>   `GOOGAPPUID`, which contains a value between 0–999:
>
> - If the cookie exists, the value is used to route the request.
> - If there is no such cookie, the request is routed randomly.
>
> If the response does not contain the `GOOGAPPUID` cookie, the app
>   first adds the `GOOGAPPUID` cookie with a random value between 0–999
>   before it is sent.
>
> Using cookies to split traffic makes it easier to accurately assign
>   users to versions. The precision for traffic routing can reach as
>   close as 0.1% to the target split. Although, cookie splitting has the
>   following limitations:
>
> - If you are writing a mobile app or running a desktop client, it needs to manage the `GOOGAPPUID` cookies. For example, when a
>     `Set-Cookie` response header is used, you must store the cookie and
>     include it with each subsequent request. Browser-based apps already
>     manage cookies in this way automatically.
> - Splitting internal requests requires extra work. All user requests that are sent from within Google's cloud infrastructure, require that
>     you forward the user's cookie with each request. For example, you must
>     forward the user's cookie in requests sent from your app to another
>     app, or to itself. Note that it is not recommended to send internal
>     requests if those requests don't originate from a user.